# Why does Eclipse of NDK application sometimes fail to start?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-ndk

Why does my run command from Eclipse of an Android NDK applications sometimes fail to start with the following error in the console:

```
[2014-04-16 15:18:53 - app] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.domain.app/.MainActivity }
[2014-04-16 15:18:53 - app] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Yet, if I just run again, it works.  Is there a way to make this error stop happening?

Comment: This occurs sometimes (/often). You just need to go *Settings > Manage Application > Select your application > Force Stop*. It means that your app is still in front on the device and you don't need to re-run again. *(I know it's weird and don't know why this occurs specially)*

Answer (score 0):

What that probably means is previously your application was `paused` and now it is getting `resumed` instead of being `started` again. If this is causing problems for your [application's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html), it means you are not properly handling `pause / resume` cycle.

You should be able to test this by pressing `home` key instead of `back` when your application is on the screen. Pressing home key will show `homescreen` application and your app will be paused. Default implementation of back key press does `stop` activity.

You can check the order events in `events log` (`adb logcat -b events`) to follow how different applications are getting effected when you start, pause, stop your application.